# Is Ambiguous column name a SQL Server only error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking at a SQL tutorial and the command that the tutorial gave gives me an error on my SQL Server Management Studio of "Ambiguous column name".  Is this error only applicable when using SQL server?

[image]

Comment: No, this error is applicable generally, and this is a very poor tutorial for it teaches you the ancient `join` syntax that you should drop. Also please see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the tutorial the query was suppose to be wrong.

Comment: It's a bad tutorial because comma-separated JOIN syntax has been deprecated since the introduction of SQL-92 almost 30 years ago.

Comment: [bad habits to kick - old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). A good tutorial will explain things better by showing the bad habit, the problems it causes, a better approach and why it is both better and fixes the earlier problems. And don't start thinking that any syntax rules or habits you learn for SQL Server apply to every other sql dialect. There are many differences - don't add to your struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all.  In reality, a column reference in SQL should always be qualified -- meaning that it should say what table it comes from.  You can think of the unqualified names as a short-hand.  The SQL engine does the favor of figuring out the table when it can.  And when a column is in multiple tables, it cannot figure it out.

Your queries should be readable and unambiguous.   In your case, your code should look something like this:

```
select c.cname
from college c join
     apply a
     on c.cname = a.cname
where c.enrollment > 2000 and a.major = 'CS';
```

Note:  This is guessing where `enrollment` and `major` are coming from, because there is not enough information in your query to figure this out.

Also, this uses proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause, even if your course/tutorial materials do so.  In fact, that alone suggests that they are way out-of-date (decades old).

Also, use table aliases (the abbreviations) so queries are simpler to write and to read.